# Is there a way to omit the jsdoc sidebar in tutorials?

Tags: html, jsdoc

I'm using jsdoc to document a repo. I also use the tutorials jsdoc feature.

My tutorials are self contained html files that are wide enough that jsdoc's sidebar cause them to not display properly.

Is there a way for jsdoc to just include the tutorials as-is, or to simply omit the sidebar which really is not needed for the tutorials?